# Streams and Collectors.toMap() - two approaches?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Among the below two code snippets - which one is preferable.

**Approach -1**

```
public Map<String, List<MyObj>> approach1(
            Iterable<? extends String> keys) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(keys.spliterator(), false)
                .map(dt -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(dt, load(dt)))
                .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a, HashMap::new));
    }
```

**Approach - 2**

```
public Map<String, List<MyObj>> approach2(
            Iterable<? extends String> keys)  {
        return StreamSupport.stream(keys.spliterator(), false)
                .collect(toMap(dt -> dt, k -> load(dt), (a, b) -> a, HashMap::new));
    }
```

In **approach1**, a map entry is explicitly created and then mapped in `toMap` using `getKey` and `getValue`, does this have any advantage or **approach2** which is more direct is equally good.

Followup Question: If the entries in Iterable `keys` or not sorted, does the merge function `(a, b) -> a` give same result for the same entries in `keys` but in different order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the entries in Iterable keys or **not sorted**, does the merge function `(a, b) -> a` give same result for the same entries in keys but in different order.

It has nothing to do with sorting.

Where behavior of the *mergeFunction* is deterministic or not depends on whether the source is **ordered** or not (ordered simply means predictable order of iteration, elements might not be sorted anyhow). If it's the case, `Spliterator` produced from the given `Iterable` would have a characteristic `Spliterator.ORDERED`.

That would dictate if the resulting Stream would be *ordered* or *unordered*.

For instance, `HashSet` has no particular order of iteration, opposed to collections like `ArrayList`, `ArrayDeque`, etc. guarantee deterministic order of iteration.

***Note:** certain methods offered by Stream API that can change the ordering of the pipeline. Operation* `unordered()` *will loosen ordering constraint (if the stream was ordered), and* `sorted()` *would impose ordering.*

According to the documentation of [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)):

> mergeFunction - a merge function, used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key, as supplied to `Map.merge(Object, Object, BiFunction)`

So in the ordered stream, *mergeFunction* `(a, b) -> a` would preserve the value that has been produced from the stream element that occur earlier in the stream. But if the stream is unordered, elements can be consumed by the Collector in any order, and it would be not possible to predict which value would end up in the resulting Map.

Regarding the question about the difference between the two streams, map() operation in the first snippet is redundant, since it only creates unnecessary intermediate `Map.Entry` instances. It looks like you've added this operation just for the purpose of to be able to apply method references in the Collector, it's not justifiable. Object creation is not happening for free, and it might not be obvious for the reader of the code why do you need this intermediate transformation.

Also, note specifying *mapFactory* `HashMap::new` inside the Collector in both snippets is pointless because a general purpose implementation of the `Map` interface in the form of `HashMap` or something that might come as its recommended replacement in the future would be given to you by default. So *mapFactory* can be omitted if you're fine with getting a `HashMap` a result of the stream execution. The use case for *four-args* version of `toMap` expecting *mapFactory* is when you need a `TreeMap`, `EnumMap`, or any other *special purpose* implementation.

Comment: `The use case for four-args version of toMap expecting mapFactory is when you need a TreeMap, EnumMap, or any other special purpose implementation.` - great point. +1

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code you have provided, Both approaches will produce the same result.

The followup Question:
If the entries in Iterable `keys` are not sorted then the merge function (`a, b) -> a` may give different results depending on the order in which the entries are processed. This is because the merge function is used to resolve conflicts when two elements are mapped to the same `key` and the order may affect which element is retained in `map`,
if the `keys` are sorted  then the merge function will give same result